# how can i retrieve all conditional access policies AzureAD?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I'm working on a pipeline that retrieves all **conditional access policies** from **Azure active directory** and make an csv list

my problem is that I found a command `get-azureadmsconditionalaccesspolicy` that lists them but it's not showing all the policies that exists does anyone know how to solve it ?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment to get the Azure Conditional Access policy using PowerShell**

I have created 2 conditional access policies like below.

[image]

> In order to use **GetAzureADMSConditionalAccessPolicy** command, first you have to install required version of PowerShell module to get all policies using PowerShell.

Here is the **PowerShell** command to know the required version of PowerShell module.

```
Get-command *conditional*
```

[image]

**I have installed both the versions**

```
Install-Module -Name AzureAD -RequiredVersion 2.0.2.140
Install-Module -Name AzureADPreview -RequiredVersion 2.0.2.149
```

**Connect to Azure AD**

```
Connect-AzureAD
```

**Get all Azure Conditional Access policies**

```
Get-AzureADMSConditionalAccessPolicy
```

[image]

**Get Azure conditional Access policies with filter conditions**

```
Get-AzureADMSConditionalAccessPolicy|FT DisplayName,Id
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your response but the probleme persist i have 8 policies but it only shows 5 :(

Comment: Hi @kingliiis, If you create policy with Azure Template, by default policy Name comes with CA006: kindly remove the starting value CA006: value and save the policy and check the same.